# is there an IMGINPUTS environment variable?

Tags: texinputs

Two env variables  TEXINPUTS and BIBINPUTS  provide great convenience for a user to put multiple sty files and bib files in dirs different from the current working dir for tex.

Is there is similar env variable one can set to point to a dir that holds a bunch of images files?

The \graphicspath{} command inside a tex file can do the job, but it is not as convenient as a possible IMGINPUTS env variable.
The reason an env var is more convenient is that you can easily use $HOME or ~ etc, but I am not sure if \graphicspath{} can easily recognize $HOME etc

Thanks

Comment: To latex an image is just a file, so gfx is covered by the normal `TEXINPUTS` variable. Though, for most proi think graphicspath is better because system variables are easily forgotten

Comment: Great, thank you!